# How to forbid specific special charachters in wordpress password

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I would like a help in changing rules in password requirements. I am trying to find how to prevent user create a password with including charachters like < > ‘ = `
Does anyone know a way of doing this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a plugin. I can recommend you the following two:

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-password-strength-settings/
https://ithemes.com/security/wordpress-password-security/

But as a postscript, what's the point of that users should not using special characters in their passwords? This should actually be required!